# Remove duplicate in combobox in Data Entry Form (Microsoft Access 2010)

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010, duplicates

I am developing a simple database for a competition by Microsoft Access 2010. There are one issue that I am facing right now and I need your help.

In my table Schools, I have a list of school that participate in the competition, with the year they participate (the competition is organized every year and 1 school can participate in many years). I also have another table called Team, which contain teams that come from different schools, and I create a Data Entry Form for this entity. And to make it easy to type in, I create a combobox for school list, so that when people type in team information, they can easily choose their school name from the list.

However, because 1 school can participate in many years, then there are duplicates in my combobox. Could you please help me how to remove the duplicates?

I tried SELECT DISTINCT but it did not work.

Any recommend? Thks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have enough information to give you the help you want, but if I am understanding you correctly you may want to use GROUP BY in your query for the combo box.

Something like this (I don't what your field name is so I used "SchoolName")

SELECT Schools.SchoolName
FROM Schools
GROUP BY Schools.SchoolName;

Hopefully this helps